# Nvidia logo appears for a split second then back to console login

Tags: boot, 16.04, nvidia, upgrade, proprietary

I just upgraded to 16.04 from 14.04 and I installed the nvidia proprietary drivers. After rebooting, I see the nvidia logo for a split second. Then the screen goes black and I end up at the console with a login prompt. Not sure why this happens? I would like to use the proprietary drivers so that I can use Kodi with accelerated graphics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I was close. After installing the proprietary drivers, I had to blacklist the noveau drivers. Here's what I did:

Edit /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf

Add the following lines:

```
blacklist nouveau
blacklist lbm-nouveau
options nouveau modeset=0
alias nouveau off
alias lbm-nouveau off
```

Now restart and you should now have the nvidia drivers load and stay loaded.